# JavaScript check if URL on different domain is reachable

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, same-origin-policy

Is it possible to check if a URL on a different domain is reachable in JS? Ajax calls work fine, but only if the resource is in the same domain.

e.g.

http://placehold.it/150.png => is reachable

http://blabla.blabla => is not reachable

Comment: Is it always an image you want to test, or can it be a document?

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot do this via AJAX/Javascript as it would violate cross-domain policy. Unless the target domain:

- Explicitly declares a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.
- Implements JSONp

You will need a server-side proxy in between.

Answer (score 0):

It would work if its on a different domain as long as the server implements [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) where obviously your server web service should be returning JSON too. Or you will have to use a proxy for issuing your cross domain requests.

If you're using php I suggest checking out [Simple PHP Proxy](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/) if you're using Python check out [Proxypy](https://github.com/aymanfarhat/proxypy)